# How do I dynamically adjust css using javascript for sub menu and sub sub menu items that overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I am building a menu in CSS and would like to ensure that sub menus and sub-sub menus stay onscreen and do not overflow. It is for a responsive html layout and I would like to dynamically adjust CSS so that when the screen is resized, menu items that WERE being affected by the fix that are now perhaps on the next line down and on the far left reset... here is what I have tried.. (My css and javascript is poor)

```
HTML:
    <body>
    <div class="container">

    <div id='cssmenu'>

    <ul class='dropdown'>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
   <ul>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>

CSS:




    body {
        background:red;
    }
    .container {
        margin:30px;
        background:#fff;
        padding-bottom:400px;
    }
    .dropdown, .dropdown li, .dropdown ul {
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .dropdown {
        position:relative;
        z-index:10000;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
    .dropdown ul {
        position:absolute;
        top:100%;
        visibility:hidden;
        display:none;
        z-index:900;
        width:16em;
    }
    .dropdown ul ul {
        top:0;
    }
    .dropdown li {
        position:relative;
        float:left;
    }
    .dropdown li:hover {
        z-index:910;
    }

    .dropdown ul:hover, .dropdown li:hover > ul, .dropdown a:hover + ul, .dropdown a:focus + ul {
        visibility:visible;
        display:block;
    }
    .dropdown a {
        display:block;
        background:#000;
        color:#fff;
        padding:1em 2em;
    }
    .dropdown ul li {
        width:100%;
    }
    .dropdown li:hover a {
        background:#333;
    }
    .dropdown li a:focus, .dropdown li a:hover {
        background:#666;
    }

    .dropdown .nonedge ul li ul li{
      left:100%;
    }
    .dropdown .edge ul {
    right:0px;
     }

    .dropdown .edge ul li ul {
      left:-100%;
     }





JAVASCRIPT



    $(function () {

    $(".dropdown li").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
        if ($('ul', this).length) {
            var elm = $('ul:first', this);
            var off = elm.offset();
            var l = off.left;
            var w = elm.width();
            var docH = $(".container").height();
            var docW = $(".container").width();

            var isEntirelyVisible = (l + w <= docW);

            if (!isEntirelyVisible) {
                $(this).addClass('edge');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('edge');
            }
        }
    });
    });
    $(function () {

    $(".dropdown li").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
        if ($('ul', this).length) {
            var elm = $('ul:first', this);
            var off = elm.offset();
            var l = off.left;
            var w = elm.width();
            var docH = $(".container").height();
            var docW = $(".container").width();

            var isEntirelyVisible = (l + w <= docW);

            if (!isEntirelyVisible) {
                $(this).removeClass('nonedge');
              } else {  
               $(this).addClass('nonedge');
     }
     }
    });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G7qfq/739/

Comment: I ended up doing it like this... http://jsfiddle.net/qg487uL0/2/

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
 });
</script>
```

**Sub Menu**

```
/* CSS: */
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>

/* JS: */
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
 });
</script>
```